# VBA VookUP Copy Paste Based on Column

Tags: vba

I have a name of companies and tickers in Column P and Q and What I am trying to get is voookup of Column R to Column P and if Value Matches then paste it to Column T. I have this voolup code = "=VLOOKUP(R2,P:Q,2,FALSE)" and trying to covert it to VBA.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim p, q, r, t As String

Sub esindia()

For i = 2 To 20000 Step 1

p = Sheet1.Range("p2" & i)
q = Sheet1.Range("q2" & i)
r = Sheet1.Range("r2" & i)
t = Sheet1.Range("t2" & i)

    If r = p Then
     t = r
     Sheet1.Range("t" & i) = r
   Else
     p = r
     Sheet1.Range("t" & i) = r
 End If
Next

End Sub
```

Am I Missing anything here, help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want formulas or values placed in your cells

Answer (score 0):

The `With` block is a lot and can be broken out into individual variables for better readability if you wanted.

Breaking it apart

1. `ThisWorkbook`
2. `Sheets("Sheet1")`
3. `Range("T2:T" & LROw)`
4. Where `LRow` = `Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)`

---

```
Sub MyVlookup()

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("T2:T" & Range("T"  & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(R2, P:Q, 2, 0)"
    .Value = .Value 'Remove this if you want the formula to show in the sheet
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this, forgot to mention that instead to R2, I would like to check data for each row means r2, r3, r4 etc.. Is it possible.

Comment: I tested it, it was doing only for R2.

Comment: How many rows do you have? So on the 3rd row, it is still looking at `R2`?

Comment: For X = 2 To 100

Cells(X, 5).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(D" & X & ",A:B,2,FALSE)"

Next X

With Range("E2:E100")
    .Value = .Value

End With